# log4net sends several emails instead of just one

Tags: email, log4net

I use log4net as a logging system. However it sends 940 emails instead of just one email. Does anyone how i can fix this so it would just only send one email with all the information?

here is my config file

```
<appender name="EmailAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
  <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
  <subject value="Tribess Rating Error Report" />
  <to value="climburg@deanone.nl" />
  <from value="TribessRatingChecker &lt;noreply@onexs.com&gt;" />
  <smtpHost value="smtp-out.onexs.com" />
  <bufferSize value="1000" />
  <lossy value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff} %-5level - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is not in the appender, it is in your code. It maybe looks like al messages are send at the same time because of the 1000 size buffer. You have to fix the place where the logging takes place. If you want to have the messages directly you need to set the buffer to 1.

Comment: No i don't want them directly i want them when the program closes. It should send one log file at the end wich contain all the log messages. now it sends several emails ( 940). the first email contains 4 log messages, the second email contains 2 log messages and the 3th and further emails contains 1 log message